# Pass parameters to constructor, when initializing a lazy instance

Tags: c#, constructor, mef, lazy-initialization

As I know if a variable is declared `Lazy`, then its constructor is called when we use the `Value` property.

I need to pass some parameters to this `Lazy` instance but cannot find the correct syntax.
This is not my design, I'm using MEF and `ExportFactory`, it returns me `Lazy` instances of my parts. My parts have constructors and I need to call these constructors with some parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MEF doesn't have a built-in way for you to pass constructor parameters to a part when you create it with an ExportFactory.  Something like what Wim Coenen suggests is probably the best way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 9):

You could export your own `Func` instead:

```
public class FooFactory
{
    [Export(typeof(Func<string,int,ExportLifetimeContext<IFoo>>))]
    public ExportLifetimeContext<IFoo> CreateFoo(string param1, int param2)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo(param1, param2);
        return new ExportLifetimeContext<IFoo>(foo,
            delegate
            {
                // Clean-up action code goes here. The client might not be able 
                // to do this through the IFoo interface because it might not
                // even expose a Dispose method.
                //
                // If you created other hidden dependencies in order to construct
                // Foo, you could also clean them up here. 
                foo.Dispose();
            });
    }
}
```

and import it elsewhere:

```
[Export(typeof(ISomething))]
public class FooUser : ISomething
{
    private readonly Func<string,int,ExportLifetimeContext<IFoo>> fooFactory;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public FooUser(Func<string,int,ExportLifetimeContext<IFoo>> fooFactory)
    {
        this.fooFactory = fooFactory;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        using (var fooLifetime = this.fooFactory("hello", 3))
        {
            IFoo foo = fooLifetime.Value;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't need the clean-up action then you could simplify this considerably by throwing out all the `ExportLifetimeContext` stuff.

However, some implementations of `IFoo` might be disposable (or depend on other disposable objects) while others are not. So the most correct thing to do is to build a "I'm done with this object" signal into the abstraction, which is what `ExportLifetimeContext` provides.

Comment: Parts are not fully trusted in my case. Also since I have no idea (from exporter side) who is calling the exported Func so I need some identifier to be passed as parameter of the function. This way the part is claiming who he is. This is a security hole sine a part can claim to be somebody else and I will return sensitive data of another part to this one. This problem can be solved by design at the point I'm creating the object. At that point, using metadata, I know which part I'm creating and easily can inject it's specific dependencies to its constructor.

Comment: @Wim: I load plugins from a folder. Your line Foo foo = new Foo(param1, param2) gives me a problem as I do not know "Foo" at time of implementation. This works well with ExportFactory, but now I have need to pass a parameter to one type of ViewModel in the plugins. Any suggestions?

Comment: @PatrickS: I guess you could scan the assemblies for types implementing `IFoo` yourself, and then invoke the constructor via reflection. It's a bit too far outside the scope of the original question to answer in full detail here, as I don't think MEF would be much help for that.