# Custom 'ExportFactory'

Tags: c#, export, mef, factory

A desktop application using `MEF` imports many 'ServiceProviders'. Each part (ServiceProvider) is a class inside a separate DLL.
All DLLs are in 'Plugin" folder which is used by desktop application.

Since I needed new Instances of my parts, `ExportFactory` was the best choice. The problem is my parts have constructors. I need pass some parameters into constructor of the part which is not supported by `ExportFactory` (MEF2, Preview2).

I need something like this:

```
// Each part has its own dependency
Dependency dependency = LoadDependency(myPart.Metedata["Name"]);
// Injecting dependency into part's constructor
myPart.CreateExport(dependency);
```

I don't want import anything from my parts-side.

A sample project (with parameter-less constructor) can be found [here](http://rapidshare.com/files/436594006/MEF.zip).

Comment: I'm confused. You talk about `MyExportFactory` but then you show a class called `SrviceProviderFactory`. You also define a method `CreateServiceProvider` but then elsewhere you call `CreateMyExport`. Did you rename things while writing the question?

Answer (score 6):

When MEF sees an import of the type `ExportFactory<IFoo>`, it treats this in a special way. Instead of looking literally for an `ExportFactory<IFoo>` export, it looks instead for a `IFoo` export and magically generates a factory for that type.

Your mistake is that you expect this magic to also automatically work for your own alternative to `ExportFactory` which you called `SrviceProviderFactory`. This is not true. When you import `SrviceProviderFactory<IFoo,IFooMetadata>` somewhere, MEF literally looks for an export of that type.

The straightforward solution is to give it this export. Manually export a factory for each IServiceProvider implementation. For example, if you have a `FooServiceProvider`:

```
public class FooServiceProvider : IServiceProvider
{
    public FooServiceProvider(Dependency dependency)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you also need to have a FooServiceProviderFactory:

```
[Export(typeof(IServiceProviderFactory))]
[ExportMetaData("foo", "bar")]
public class FooServiceProviderFactory : IServiceProviderFactory
{
    public IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(Dependency d)
    {
       return new FooServiceProvider(d);
    }
}
```

And then your importer can select the right factory based on metadata:

```
public class FactoryUser
{
    [ImportMany]
    public Lazy<IServiceProviderFactory,IDictionary<string,object>>[] Factories 
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
       var factory = Factories.First(x => x.Metadata["foo"] == "bar").Value;
       var serviceProvider = factory.CreateServiceProvider(someDependency);
       ...
    }
}
```

The annoying thing here is that for each service provider implementation, you also need to create and export a factory implementation. You can save work by creating a common factory base class (like your `SrviceProviderFactory`) but you still have to derive specific classes because you can't use generic type parameters in MEF exports. **update**: I believe .NET 4.5 now supports exporting open generic types.

That's why [I already suggested you export `Func` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396744/pass-parameters-to-constructor-when-initializing-a-lazy-instance/4399652#4399652), but apparently you didn't like that answer.

You could also try to replicate the `ExportFactory` magic. This is possible but a very advanced use case of MEF. If you want to do that I suggest you take a look at the MEF sources of `ExportFactoryProvider` to see how to build your own implementation with support for parameters.