# MEF ExportFactory<T> - Any way to pass a parameter value prior to creating an export?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, initialization, mef, dependency-properties

```
Factory.CreateExport() create's a ExportLifetimeContext<T>
```

Is there any way to actually pass in a parameter to it so it creates it with a parameter. I found some example code that wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but it had something called `Dependency` and I'm wondering if that's the right direction to look at?

---

Update:

The link's answer has it, though I'm not sure if that's like "Foo" or an actual Object.
[Custom 'ExportFactory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417437/custom-exportfactory)

Comment: Please provide the link you found.